# Angular $resource JSON Callback not working - is this best practice?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm creating a resource to pass data into my controller for an existing api that need to hook into. I am not able to modify the back end unfortunately.

My Resource factory currently looks like this:

'use strict';

```
        angular.module('XXX')
        .factory('elements', function (
            $resource
        ) {
            return $resource('http://XXX/api/v1/elements/:id',
                {
                    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
                    id: '@id'
                },
                {
                    query: {
                        method: 'JSONP',
                        params: {
                            id: '@id'
                        }
                    },
                    all: {
                        method: 'JSONP',
                        params: {}
                    }
                }
            );
        });
```

The elements.query() works fine, however the elements.all() does not work unfortunately. I did notice that in the returned content in my network tab, begins with angular.callbacks._2([{... DATA...}]) - this doesn't seem right to me.

UPDATE.....

OK so i've got it working with this:

```
    angular.module('XXX')
    .factory('element', function (
        $resource
    ) {
        return $resource('http://XXX/api/v1/elements/:id',
            {
                id: '@id',
                        callback : 'JSON_CALLBACK',
            },
            {
                query: {
                    method: 'JSONP',
                    params: {
                        id: '@id'
                    }
                },
                all: {
                    method: 'JSONP',
                    isArray: true,
                    params: {
                        callback : 'JSON_CALLBACK',
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

however the json that it returns to the console comes in as an array.. I am able to parse it for use, but just wondering now if this is best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the way **isArray** is meant for.
You need the isArray flag, because angular has to create an empty Object - in this case an Array - *before* the request is sent. So all bindings will work, because you have the same reference. At the time the result has arrived, it will be populated to your variable, the result object / array.

We are doing the service calls like this, maybe it will help you:

```
.factory('Person', function($resource, AppConfig) {
   var Person = $resource(AppConfig.remoteURL + '/person/:id', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET'},
      queryAll: {method:'GET', isArray: true},
      create: {method:'POST'},
      update: {method: 'PUT'}});

   return Person;
});
```

and call it like this:

```
Person.queryAll(function (result) {
   angular.isArray(result); // should be true
}, function (error) 
{
    //doh!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to specify a custom transformResponse to convert pull the data out of the array form.

Snippet from [$resource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

`transformResponse – {function(data, headersGetter)|Array.<function(data, headersGetter)>}` – transform function or an array of such functions. The transform function takes the http response body and headers and returns its transformed (typically deserialized) version.

So your code would be something along the lines of:

```
all: {
  method: 'JSONP',
  isArray: true,
  params: {
    callback : 'JSON_CALLBACK',
  },
  transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) {
     return data.[....].DATA;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, $resource is used for RESTful APIs. JSONP only uses GET.

So, I would use $http.JSONP instead of $resource for this.

In your code, can you let your server-side support CORS?